# Amplify timeout when doing Auth calls

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, jestjs, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I set up auth through API, and I'd like to signin with created and confirmed cognito user in this way:

```
describe("Tests authentication", () => {
    it("should signup/signin", async () => {

    const loggedin = await Auth.signIn('user@email.com', 'password')
}
```

However I am getting timeout error.
At the same time signup works well, adn if I am input wrong username/password it prompts me error message, (so cognito is reachable).
The timeout happens for admin queries.

Any help is much appreciated.

This occurs in jest test only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It because Api was slow, and I increase by setting 3rd argument of "it" preferred timeout. Changing Axios timeout will not fix this.